# Memory and Storage in Android Devices

Tags: android, memory, storage, ram

My android device has the following configuration.

[image]

I wish to know the function of each type of memory.As far as PC/Laptops are considered ROM is type of memory which is configured by the manufacturer and we cannot write on it. BIOS chip is a ROM. RAM is a volatile memory which is erased every time power is turned off. Programs are loaded into the RAM(memory) and are executed bu the processor.Extrenal memory can be any pther flash memory like a pendrive or a external HDD.

What are the analogous contexts in android. And what is this internal memory? Whenever I install any app by default it gets installed in this internal memory and my device give me an option to move the app from this internal memory to internal SD card. Can anyone point out the functionalities of these memory types in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAM: volatile, run-time memory for app execution

Internal Memory: Used for phone capabilities, app installations and their data, not available to the device user. wont be visible even in the file explorer. [unless your device is rooted]

Internal SD Card: Used to save all types of files and media. Accessible to the user as well as apps. Visible in the file explorer.

External SD Card: expandable memory by the use of an SD card, visible and accessible to users.

**EDIT:**  First three are available by default in the device.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a good understand of the situation. It is really much the same for android. RAM for running apps. Internal (similar to pc harddisk - functionality wise) and external, well.. external harddisk.

Answer (score 0):

Internal memory is the memory that is installed by the manufacturer. This memory is always available but if it is full some important phone features may have problems to work (for example on Android 2.2 Devices you want receive Text Messages if memory is below 20MB).

The external/expandable memory is memory that is supplied by an SD-Card. If you save an App on the SD-Card this app won't work if anymore if the SD-Card is removed or accessed on another device via USB. Therefore if your app has alarm features or a desktop widget those won't work while the external memory is not available, so if those are important features forbid saving to external memory in your manifest.

If you save data from your app you can also write to external storage. This way you can leave data on the phone that is not deleted once the app is deleted, but external memory has no right management, every app can read, or delete your data.